# Update MongoDB Object with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm afraid I have a small problem with my project with Spring and MongoDB.
I have saved a user, which is shown under Email,Name and another object(workplace).

```
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private WorkPlace workPlace;
```

I need the possibility to change the Workplace. I have not found anything reasonable in the Internet for an update. Only a "save" method to update the object.
The problem is, if I want to update the object, he takes the user, changes the Workplace and creates a new object. But I don't need a new object. The object is unique by its email address, because it only exists once.
I need only to change the Workplace

```
@PostMapping("/update")
    public User update(@RequestParam String email, @RequestBody Workplace workplace ) {
        User u = repository.findByEmail(email);
        u.setWorkplace(workplace);
        return repository.save(u);

    }
```

I have set the repository as follows:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;


@Repository
public interface ModelRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    public User findByEmail(String email);  
}
```

Comment: did you define the `email` to be the id by annotationg it with `@Id`?

Comment: I also try this with the annotation `@ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an `@Id` annotated property at your `User` class. Otherwise Spring Data MongoDB does not find an existing identifier and will do an insert of the object.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document

@Document(collection="users")
class User {
    @Id
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private Workplace workplace;
}
```

If an entity is set, then a save instead of an insert is done.

Comment: Thanks! Yes without Id he has always automatically created one and included it in the document. And with this annotation I can search with "findById" and not as usual with "findByEmail" or?

Comment: `findByEmail` you need the name of the property, and that's still `email`